# Testing If a Three/Four Digit Number is Prime or Not

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Thank you for providing such great help. Thanks to math.stack site.

I would like to know a good method to test any three/four digit number prime or not? I don't want to go any C or Java or any computer related calculations. I want to know the method, which will help to us to know the number is prime or not? could you share the method.

---

I have drawn the formula of checking the given number is prime or not form Prof. Gandhi's lecture series. That is: In expansion of $(x-1)^n - (x^n-1)$, check all the coefficients are of the expansion is divisible by $n$, then $n$ is prime, otherwise not. I could not find proof of the cited above. However, it is working for some numbers, as I checked up to primes below 10000. Could you prove this, how $(x-1)^n - (x^n-1)$ is working and how it is related to $n$ and coefficients of expansion of $(x-1)^n - (x^n-1)$?

Comment: Looks like you're talking about the AKS primality test: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AKS_primality_test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Method:1**

Checking if all the coefficients are divisible by $n$ is equivalent to saying that       $$n |(x-1)^n - (x^n-1)$$ for some $x \in Z$ and $n$ being a prime.

Using Fermat's Theorem which states that:$$x^p \equiv x \mod p$$ where $p$ is a prime and $x \in Z$.

Hence we have,

$(x-1)^n \equiv x-1 \mod n$ and $x^n \equiv x \mod n$

The result we get is:

$(x-1)^n - (x^n-1) \equiv x-1 -x+1 \equiv 0 \mod n$.

Hence proved.

**Method:2**

It is enough to prove that $$ n | {n \choose r}$$ for $0 \lt r \lt n$.

$${n \choose r} ={n! \over (n-r)!r!}$$

Observe that the denominator contains integers which are $\lt n$ for any $r$. Since, $n$ is a prime, none of the integers in the denominator divides it. Hence, there will be an $n$ left in the each term, which means it is divisible by $n$.

Hence Proved.

**Other efficient methods for Primality testing:**

There are other methods for primality test, which are far more efficient than the one you stated. Since, you are only interested in 3/4 digit numbers, you can apply [sieve of eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) which gives you all the primes in $O(N)$ time.

Your method takes $O(N)$ per primality test which is quite inefficient. Another method is to check whether the number has divisors and this can be done in $O(\sqrt N)$.

Another method is using probabilistic primality testing algorithm like [Miller-Rabin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test) primality test where the time complexity is reduced further.

Comment: ! Your proof is amazing. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

For such tiny numbers, the fastest computer method for almost any machine is trial division.  The simplest way would be to store a small table of primes up to 100 then loop checking divisibility, and when testprime * testprime > n, you're done and the result is prime (because you have tested divisibility by all primes $\le \lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor$).  Because of the small size, you can optimize a little more if desired to only do three range comparisons instead of twenty five, and hard code the few primes.

This is going to be much faster than testing n-1 binomials, AKS, or Fermat or M-R tests for this tiny size.  If you expand to larger numbers, look at Miller-Rabin tests with [deterministic bases](http://miller-rabin.appspot.com/) or [BPSW](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baillie%E2%80%93PSW_primality_test).  Assuming programmed correctly, these will be completely correct for all numbers less than $2^{64}$.

I know AKS is sexy, fun, and a favorite of internet forums.  You're welcome to implement it.  But it is not a practical algorithm (in that there are multiple equivalent methods that are millions of times faster).

Comment: ! can you discuss or give hints of implementing AKS please...

Comment: The [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AKS_primality_test) has a lot of info about it, including links.  Programming Praxis has a [blog entry](http://programmingpraxis.com/2012/10/05/aks-primality-prover-part-2/) about it.  The [AKS paper](http://www.cse.iitk.ac.in/users/manindra/algebra/primality_v6.pdf]() will answer a lot of questions.  [AKS paper](http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/2005-42-01/S0273-0979-04-01037-7/home.html) fills in more details.  Let me know if you want links to implementations in C, C+GMP, C+NTL, Perl, etc.

Comment: [RosettaCode](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/AKS_test_for_primes) has implementations of the beginning lemma which make interesting reading, although the method is completely impractical.

Again, AKS is interesting, and important for the theory, but its mention in a question of "good method to test any three/four digit number prime or not" is bizarre.  Do people seriously suggest [Fürer's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F%C3%BCrer%27s_algorithm) when asked how to multiply 2-digit numbers?

Answer (score 0):

Since primes with 3-4 decimal digits are small, the most effective way to determine primality is to check to see if it has any prime divisors in the interval $[2, \sqrt{n}]$. You could alternatively use a primality test, which is not guaranteed to be correct (ie., there is a margin of error).

Here are links to a couple such tests:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas_primality_test
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proth%27s_theorem

Comment: @mlo105! I am re editing my question. please check.